# TypeError: Impossible to find getCell function in the Sheet object

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get some data from a Google Sheet to insert in two arrays with a `for` loop but I think I'm using the wrong methods.

This is the code:

```
function regValori() {
    var datAgg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("datiaggiornati");
    var f5 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Foglio5");
    var CValue = new Array();
    var CName = new Array();

    CValue.lenght = datAgg.getRange("B1").getValue();
    CName.lenght = CValue.lenght;

    for (var i = 0; i <= CValue.lenght; i++)
    { 
        CValue[i] = datAgg.getCell(i, 16).getValue();
        CName[i] = datAgg.getCell(i+2, 1).getValue();
    }
    var riga = f5.getRange("B2").getValue();
      for (x = 3; x <= numCrypto; x++);
        for (i=0;i<numCrypto;i++);
          {
            f5.getRange(riga, x).setValue(valCrypto[r+i]);
            f5.getRange(2,numCrypto).setValue(nomiCrypto[r+i]);
          }
        }
```

The error:

> TypeError: Impossible to find getCell function in the Sheet object

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How does your data look like, and which cell are you trying to get?

Comment: function must read a set of values from one sheet and insert it in another one (same google document). The array must be dynamic because data can varies but they change together (i.e. if the first set of value is 14 than the other one is 14 too). Sheet is about cryptocurrencies. I want to have a sheet that saves their value (it changes continuosly) each day at a scheduled time. For this reason, function must read cryptocurrencies names (first array) and cryptocurrencies value (second array) and put it in the second sheet who will display everyday a row with the updated values.

Comment: That answers what you are *trying to do*, but doesn't answer what I asked.

Comment: Anyway, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616748/typeerror-impossible-to-find-getcell-function-in-the-sheet-object/47617032#47617032) below should fix your error.

Answer (score 1):

Errors:

- `getCell()` is a method of [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getCell(Integer,Integer)), not [`Sheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- Google Sheets starts from `rowIndex = 1`

If you don't need an offset (i.e. start from a certain cell), then you can use `getRange`:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= CValue.lenght; i++)
{
    var r = i + 1; // rowIndex
    CValue[i] = datAgg.getRange(r, 16).getValue();
    CName[i] = datAgg.getRange(r+2, 1).getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution:

```
function regValori() {
    var datAgg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("datiaggiornati");
    var f5 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Foglio5");

    var riga = f5.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
    for (var i = 2; i <= 6; ++i) {
        f5.getRange(riga, i + 1).setValue(datAgg.getRange("P" + i).getValue());
        f5.getRange(2, i + 1).setValue(datAgg.getRange("A" + i).getValue());
    }
}
```

i posted another question here for the same problem and I get a perfect answer [how to use for loop to drastically reduce code lenght](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676809/how-to-use-for-loop-to-drastically-reduce-code-lenght/47677058#47677058). 
the only part I changed is this one: (var i = 2; i <= 6; ++i) with this one: (var i = 2; i <= n+1; ++i), so it can work perfectly with any variable n to get with command "var numCrypto = datAgg.getRange(1,2).getValue();"

Comment: how I can do it?

Comment: Click on the check mark on the left of your answer.