# How to use for loop to drastically reduce code length?

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop

Can someone help me to use a for loop or whatever to drastically reduce the length of this code? I just have to copy some data from `datAgg` sheet to `f5` sheet, but I would like to do it using arrays and for loop. I tried different times but it always give me error

```
  function regValori(){
      var datAgg = 
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("dati 
      aggiornati");
      var f5 = 
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Foglio5");
      var score1 = datAgg.getRange("P2").getValue(); // we want to store 
                                                        this
      //collecting names and values
      var Cname1=datAgg.getRange("A2").getValue();
      var score2 = datAgg.getRange("P3").getValue(); 
      var Cname2 = datAgg.getRange("A3").getValue();
      var score3 = datAgg.getRange("P4").getValue(); 
      var Cname3 = datAgg.getRange("A4").getValue();
      var score4 = datAgg.getRange("P5").getValue(); 
      var Cname4 = datAgg.getRange("A5").getValue();
      var score5 = datAgg.getRange("P6").getValue();
      var Cname5 = datAgg.getRange("A6").getValue();

      // get the row number where to put data
      // in correspodance with today date

      var riga = f5.getRange(2, 2).getValue();

      f5.getRange(2,3).setValue(Cname1);
      f5.getRange(2,4).setValue(Cname2);
      f5.getRange(2,5).setValue(Cname3);
      f5.getRange(2,6).setValue(Cname4);
      f5.getRange(2,7).setValue(Cname5);

     // this one to put the value for every day

     f5.getRange(riga, 3).setValue(score1);
     f5.getRange(riga, 4).setValue(score2);
     f5.getRange(riga, 5).setValue(score3);
     f5.getRange(riga, 6).setValue(score4);
     f5.getRange(riga, 7).setValue(score5);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this

```
function regValori(){
    var datAgg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("datiaggiornati");
    var f5 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Foglio5");


    var riga = f5.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
    for (var i = 2; i <= 6; ++i) {
        f5.getRange(riga, i + 1).setValue(datAgg.getRange("P" + i).getValue());
        f5.getRange(2, i + 1).setValue(datAgg.getRange("A" + i).getValue());
    }

}
```

All you need to do is have the index `i` going from the lowest to the highest value and build the strings for `getRange()`. There's also no need for so many intermediary variables or an array, since you can do every operation in one loop.

Comment: the only part I changed is this one: (var i = 2; i <= 6; ++i) with this one: (var i = 2; i <= n+1; ++i), so it can work perfectly with any variable n to get with command "var numCrypto = datAgg.getRange(1,2).getValue();"